# hardware implementation of Modulo m adder

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog, cpu-architecture

I have 8 inputs whose modulo sum i have to take with modulus m.i know algorithm for 2 input but it is not working here.
eg i have sum=sum0+sum1+sum2+sum3+sum4+sum5+sum6+sum7 and i have to take mod m of sum.How to do this rom hardware implementation point of view?
i aslo write  code but its not working
m3 is mod3

```
 always@(posedge clk)
 begin
    sum3a<=mod30+mod31;
    sum3b<=mod32+mod33;
    sum3c<=mod34+mod35;
    sum3d<=mod36+mod37;
    sum3e<=sum3a+sum3b;
    sum3f<=sum3c+sum3d;

   x31= (sum3e+sum3f);
   x32= (sum3e-m3);

    if (x32>=0 )
      sum3 <= x32;
    else
     sum3 <= x31;

 end
```

Comment: You could have sum3a to sum3f done modulo m, or have logic to substract m from final answer (you should be able to calculate pipeline this for worst-case) until answer is within 0 to m-1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not mix blocking and non-blocking assignments in the same `always` block. `sum3e`  variable depends on `sum3a` and `sum3b` but at the same time `sum3a` and `sum3b` value is changing because of non-blocking assignments,This will results in logical errors.